# Changed the Windows C:\Program Files\WindowsApps's permissons and can't open any UWP apps

Tags: windows-10, permissions, uwp

Today I was trying to System restore my OS, to the surprise of seeing an error that says that I couldn't find a copy of the WindowsApps folder, I decided to take perms of it, and then some of my UWPs stopped working, I tried everything to fix it, but no... I don't want to clean install Windows again as I have a lot of data on it, if anyone could help me ill be grateful!

Comment: Time to perform a Reset of Windows.  The solution to system restore isn't to change the permissions of a folder, that is suppose to have, those permissions.

Comment: I had at one point a potential fix for the system restore issue that seems to be common on Windows 10 but I never got around to testing it (since it requires you to have a problem and using it otherwise is a pain).

Comment: It is possible to reinstall windows, *keeping files and applications*. That *might* fix the issue. That said, *always make a disk image before making major changes.*